# Can I delete files in c:\windows\installer?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have 1 gb taken up by these install files.

c:\windows\installer\$Pathcache$\Managed...

can I safely delete these?

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not safe. These are cached MSI files from installations. They are necessary to uninstall, repair or patch the software.

However, sometimes useless orphaned MSI files can be left in there. To find and remove those you can use [msizap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370523(v=vs.85).aspx) with the `g` option.